# TextBox text content to align to center when the whole TextBox is in stretch mode

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

Hi I have a `TextBox` that I want to fill a grid that I defined for it. To do that I put it on stretch so it can be fit. The problem is then the text would be written on top and not on the center. If I make the alignment to center the the `TextBox` won't stretch anymore.

```
<TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Text="Wall Temperature [C]"/>
<TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Text="150.0"/>
<TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" Text="Wall Temperature [C]"/>
<TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" Text="150.5"/>
```

It would look like this

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify the `ControlTemplate` of the `TextBox` if you want the text in it to be vertically aligned:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextBox.Static.Border" Color="#FFABAdB3"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextBox.MouseOver.Border" Color="#FF7EB4EA"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextBox.Focus.Border" Color="#FF569DE5"/>
        <Style TargetType="TextBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                        <Border x:Name="border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                            <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Focusable="false"
                                      HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                                      VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                                      VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                                <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="border" Value="0.56"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource TextBox.MouseOver.Border}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource TextBox.Focus.Border}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>
    ...
    <TextBox Height="100" Text="Centered text..." />
</Grid>
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect, Thank you so much.